# Total newby question - How to either close the rendering window or return to the main scene window?

Tags: interface

First post, version 2.77 - 
I'll just apologize now.

I have a simple scene with a cube and a camera.
I rendered it as shown below.
How do I either close this/these rendering windows, or return to the main scene window to change things?

Thanks,

Joe
[image: simple scene with cube and camera, rendered.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press Escape, with your mouse cursor over the area.

Or, you can change the Editor with the icon bottom left the area (I guess "3d view" is the editor you're looking for)